# React Native application compile but not load

Tags: react-native, expo

I successfully eject from Expo, ran pod install inside the ios folder, then tried to open the app in ios emulator by running npx react-native run-ios.  The log states the app successfully compiled but when loading the following error comes up:

```
2020-02-16 12:03:44.254694-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151357] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2020-02-16 12:03:44.254877-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151357] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2020-02-16 12:03:44.397 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:213] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7fda7b609240> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000026f6bc0>, executor: (null))
2020-02-16 12:03:44.399272-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151357] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x7fda7b609240> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000026f6bc0>, executor: (null))
2020-02-16 12:03:44.575 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:293] Running application SantiEmpleoMobileApp ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2020-02-16 12:03:44.574862-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151357] Running application SantiEmpleoMobileApp ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2020-02-16 12:03:44.653278-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151896] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2020-02-16 12:03:44.655031-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151896] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2020-02-16 12:03:44.657333-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151897] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C4] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2020-02-16 12:03:44.680 [error][tid:NSOperationQueue 0x600000db7ea0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)][RCTCxxBridge.mm:414] Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/rey/Desktop/SantiEmpleoMobileApp/screens/JobSummary.js: Unexpected token (13:0)

[0m [90m 11 | [39m    [33mPlatform[39m[33m,[39m[0m
[0m [90m 12 | [39m    [33mButton[39m[33m,[39m[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 13 | [39m[33m<<[39m[33m<<[39m[33m<<[39m[33m<[39m [33mHEAD[39m[0m
[0m [90m    | [39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 14 | [39m[33m===[39m[33m===[39m[33m=[39m[0m
[0m [90m 15 | [39m    [33mWebView[39m[0m
[0m [90m 16 | [39m[33m>>>[39m[33m>>>[39m[33m>[39m a5e240959854bd4efc85985344bcb06af0c281ef[0m (null))
2020-02-16 12:03:44.680574-0500 SantiEmpleoMobileApp[16257:151903] Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/rey/Desktop/SantiEmpleoMobileApp/screens/JobSummary.js: Unexpected token (13:0)

\^[[0m \^[[90m 11 | \^[[39m    \^[[33mPlatform\^[[39m\^[[33m,\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 12 | \^[[39m    \^[[33mButton\^[[39m\^[[33m,\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m\^[[31m\^[[1m>\^[[22m\^[[39m\^[[90m 13 | \^[[39m\^[[33m<<\^[[39m\^[[33m<<\^[[39m\^[[33m<<\^[[39m\^[[33m<\^[[39m \^[[33mHEAD\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m    | \^[[39m\^[[31m\^[[1m^\^[[22m\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 14 | \^[[39m\^[[33m===\^[[39m\^[[33m===\^[[39m\^[[33m=\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 15 | \^[[39m    \^[[33mWebView\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 16 | \^[[39m\^[[33m>>>\^[[39m\^[[33m>>>\^[[39m\^[[33m>\^[[39m a5e240959854bd4efc85985344bcb06af0c281ef\^[[0m (null))
```

Comment: the log shows there are some syntax errors on your screen's.

Comment: ```Users/rey/Desktop/SantiEmpleoMobileApp/screens/JobSummary.js Unexpected Token 13:0```. Check this line, log says some kind of error in there

Comment: Thanks, that's the weird thing, I can render it using expo with the exact same file.  Not sure what’s happening here.